# Write values from R to a PostgreSQL table based on Row IDs

Tags: r, postgresql, dataframe, lookup

I have a PostgreSQL table `Scores` on a local server that looks like this:

```
ID   Score_X   Score_Y
1       NA        NA
2       NA        NA
3       NA        NA
4       NA        NA
```

I do a series of calculations in R that produces a dataframe `Calc_Scores` that looks like this:

```
ID   Score_X   Score_Y
1      0.53      0.81
4      0.75      0.95
```

I would like to write the scores that correspond with each ID from R to the PostgreSQL table such that the final PostgreSQL table should look like this:

```
ID   Score_X   Score_Y
1      0.53      0.81
2       NA        NA
3       NA        NA
4      0.75      0.95
```

I have a connection to the PostgreSQL table called `connection` which I setup using the function `dbConnect()`. The actual tables are quite big. What line/code in R could I use to write these scores to the PostgreSQL table? I have been looking for a similar question but couldn't find anything. I have tried

```
dbWriteTable(connection, "Scores", value = Calc_Scores, overwrite=T, append = F, row.names = F)
```

However, the entire table gets overwritten. I want only the scores to be updated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a temporary table could be an option:

```
# Create temporary table
dbWriteTable(connection, "ScoresTmp", value = Calc_Scores, overwrite=T, append = F, row.names = F)

# Update main table
dbExecute(connection,"
UPDATE Scores
SET Score_X = ScoresTmp.Score_X,
    Score_Y = ScoresTmp.Score_Y
FROM ScoresTmp 
WHERE Scores.ID = ScoresTmp.ID
")

# Clean up
dbExecute(connection,"DROP TABLE ScoresTmp")
```

Note that you should be able to create a real temporary table using the `temporary=TRUE` option : according to @Sirius comment below, it should work on a `PostGreSQL` database.
For users of an `SQLServer` database, this option doesn't work, but they can use the `#` prefix to create a temporary table.
In the example above, this would be:

```
 dbWriteTable(connection, "#ScoresTmp", value = Calc_Scores, overwrite=T, append = F, row.names = F)
```

Comment: why not add `temporary=TRUE` ? That's a lot nicer to the customer's database and means there won't be any race issues

Comment: @Sirius, thanks for your feedback : this is definetely what I would have recommended on a `SQL Server` DB I'm more familiar with,but I couldn't be sure it works on `PostgreSQL`. Perhaps @Ruan can test and confirm it's OK

Comment: @Ruan, it would be interesting to know if  `temporary=T` works in `PostGreSQL`. For `SQLServer` temporary tables  simply have the `#` prefix, without need for `temporary=T` which AFAIK doesn't work,  see [this issue](https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/issues/74).

Comment: Honestly, thats a ridiculously simple google search away. Temporary tables is such an established concept that familiarity really isn't needed. Of course please try first, but just the 3 additional lines of text with each google search confirms that they work just like they should.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this relies on the SQL 'update' and in essence you do

```
- open a connection to your database
- loop over your changeset and for each row
    - form the update statement, i.e. for example via
      cmd <- paste('update table set x=', Score_x, ', y=', 
                   Score_y, ' where id=', id)
    - submit the cmd via eg `dbSendQuery`
- close the connection
```

There are examples in `RPostgreSQL`.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not quite what I am looking for. Although it works, it takes a very long time since my actual database has about 2 million entries, having to perform an update query for each entry. Looking for a quicker way.

Comment: Well "wishing alone does not make it so".   There is AFAIK no 'partial write table' -- SQL backends often have bulk inserters which is what `dbWriteTable` resembles, Your only real alternative is to _delete_ the table and write an update.  Will that be faster?  Will that be 'safer' or better?

Comment: Deleting the table and then writing an update will not be allowed. The updates are for a company and I do not want to tamper with their database. I have access to their databases and am only allowed to make updates to these score columns. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You might upload your values in a separate table, and have queries downstream use both tables through joins and coalesce. So you really don't mess with their data at all.